# Download attribute not working in safari

Tags: html, macos, download, safari, attributes

I am using a download attribute in my link:

```
   <a style="color:white" download="myimage" href="images/myimage.jpg">Download image</a>
```

It is working very well in almost all browsers. This means, if I click on the link the image is automatically downloaded. I tested it in safari 10.1.2 on my mac and it is working fine.

But on my friends mac who is working with safari 10.0.3 it is not working. He is saying that the image is only opening in a new window but not downloading.

Why is this happening and what can I do to make it work anywhere?

Comment: @Jarla Have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_10_1.html, it was added in Safari 10.1:

> **HTML5 Download Attribute**
>   The download attribute for anchor elements
>   indicates that the link target is a download link that downloads a
>   file, instead of a navigational link. When you click a a link with the
>   download attribute, the target is downloaded as a file. Optionally,
>   the value of the download attribute provides the suggested name of the
>   file.

It doesn't seem to be available in iOS Safari 11.1 though from my own testing, which has me a bit confused. I'd expect them to be equal in standards support, based on their similar version numbering.

Comment: Mobile safari still hasn't shipped it: https://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Comment: Note that specifying a `target` attribute in Safari seems to override the `download` attribute (this does not seem to be the case in Chrome, Firefox or Opera).

Comment: Thanks @john-hascall, your comment solved the problem in my case.

Comment: I am using Safari 12.3.1 and it still doesn't work but the 13 which is in beta and will be out in a few months will support it according to the caniuse table posted in a comment above.

Answer (score 5):

try this code:

```
var element = document.createElement('a');
            var clearUrl = base64.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, '');

            // element.setAttribute('href', 'data:attachment/image' + base64);
            element.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,' + encodeURIComponent(clearUrl));
            element.setAttribute('download', 'filename.jpg');
            document.body.appendChild(element);
            element.click();
            document.body.removeChild(element)
```

This worked for me in safari version 10.0.3

Comment: works for safari 12, no filename and file type though

Comment: I am also face this issue and sorry to say that I am unable to retrive file name and extention in safari.

Comment: Holy molly this helped a lot. In the end all I had to do is to change application/pdf to application/octet-stream and mobile safari started downloading the file. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -6):

Please take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/TagS/tag_a.asp

Scroll down to attributes, and you will see that the DOWNLOAD attribute is only supported by HTML5, which, as it seems, your friend's version of Safari does not support. I recommend updating the program.

Alternatively, you can right-click on the image, then click Save As..., then download it that way.

@Jarla

Comment: Is there any alternative solution for force download images ?

Comment: @mayurkukadiya If you have access to the server that serves the images you can set the header `Content-Disposition` to `attachment`.