# Downloading base64 pdf on Safari

Tags: javascript, pdf, safari

I have a POST call that returns a base64 PDF. When I call this endpoint I convert it to a Blob and then download it. This works fine in all browsers except for Safari.

```
openPdf = () => {

  const sendObj = {
    fakeValue: 'test'
  };

  axios.post('https://fakeendpoint.com/create-pdf', sendObj)                
    .then((res) => {
      const base64URL = res.data;
      const binary = atob(base64URL.replace(/\s/g, ''));
      const len = binary.length;
      const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(len);
      const view = new Uint8Array(buffer);

      for (let i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
        view[i] = binary.charCodeAt(i);
      }

      // create the blob object with content-type "application/pdf"
      const blob = new Blob([view], { type: 'application/pdf' });
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

      const a = document.createElement('a');
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.style = 'display: none';
      a.href = url;
      a.download = 'Test.pdf';
      a.target = '_blank';
      a.click();
  });
}
```

How can I get this to work in Safari?

Comment: Please add more details about what goes wrong in Safari. Do you see any errors in the developer tools console?

Comment: No errors in console, In the network tab I can see that the POST is returning the correct data. The download never happens for the PDF.

Comment: It's opening in a new tab. Not downloading on the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like Safari doesn't follow the standards for the `a` tag. I believe [this previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47998606/4402434) identifies the root cause. From the comments in the linked answer:

> Note that specifying a target attribute in Safari seems to override the download attribute (this does not seem to be the case in Chrome, Firefox or Opera).

Try removing `a.target = '_blank'` in your code above and then testing it. It should work!

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how you would open it in a new tab with that change.

Comment: That works, thanks! The open new page is inconsequential for the download.

Answer (score 0):

from a test I made - this occurs only when the PDF is too big. (and only on mobile Safari)
I assume it is related to the length of the URL.

The only drawback from removing `target="_blank"` is that if the user click on "back" it will loose the previous page state.