# How to open pdf in new window in safari iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, safari

the code below creating an anchor that perform download funcionality on click:

```
let a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = `data:application/pdf;base64,${base64str}`;
a.download = fileName;
a.target = '_blank';
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
document.body.removeChild(a);
```

works as expected in Chrome, IE, firefox.
in safari iOS, the file is not getting downloaded but opened in the same tab.
tested on iPhone 7 13.3.1

how to perform downloading or at least open the pdf in another tab?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download attribute not working in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46690722/download-attribute-not-working-in-safari)

Comment: try with window.open("data:application/pdf," + encodeURI(pdfString));

Comment: nope. i'm using the suggested code in there - tried with and without the a.target = '_blank';

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to open pdf in new window this way:

```js
function openInNewTab(url) {
   window.open(url, '_blank').focus();
}

openInNewTab("https://example.com/");
```

Answer comes originally from here: [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window)

Comment: How to open in new window is also part of question - I posted it, because safari seems still to have problems with `download` attribute (in my case it also only opens PDF inside actual window), and also `target="_blank"` doesn't change anything, so the snippet above might be an alternative way.