# Display PDF in base64 in a new tab in iPad (Safari or Chrome for iOs) 2021

Tags: ios, angular, typescript, ipad, safari

I am working in an Angular web app, in which I am getting a base64 string from a backend API, which represents a PDF file. I want to open that PDF in a new tab. I have tried using Blobs, iframes, and all sorts of methods, all of which seem to work in my Mac's chrome and safari, and they even work on a simulated iPad (using XCode and the simulated device's safari) but they don't work on the real device (iPad). This is the code I use to open a PDF in a new tab, both supporting chrome and safari:

First, I determine if the browser is safari. If this is the case, I pre-open the new window, as opening a new tab from inside an XHR call is forbidden in safari:

```
var isSafari =
  navigator.vendor &&
  navigator.vendor.indexOf('Apple') > -1 &&
  navigator.userAgent &&
  navigator.userAgent.indexOf('CriOS') == -1 &&
  navigator.userAgent.indexOf('FxiOS') == -1;
if (isSafari) {
  var newWindow = window.open('', '_blank');
}
```

Then, I make my XHR call to get the PDF url in base64, and I create a Blob out of it:

```
this.dataService
  .getPDFUrl(this.data.code)
  .subscribe((res) => {
      this.pdfUrl = res.message;
      var byteCharacters = atob(this.pdfUrl);
      var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
      for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
        byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
      }
      var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
      var file = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/pdf;base64' });
      this.pdfUrl = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(file);
      //If browser is Safari, use a Reader to display the PDF in the previously opened window
      if (isSafari) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function (e) {
          newWindow.location.href = reader.result as string;
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      } else {
        //If browser is not Safari, open a new window (works in chrome)
        window.open(this.pdfUrl, '_blank');
      }
  });
```

I have tried this and many other approaches, and none of them work on a real iPad, even though they do work on a simulated iPad.

Can you provide me with any guidance about how to get the PDF in base64 to properly display in a new tab in an iPad? I need it to work in iOs Safari or in Chrome for iOs (I understand they are both internally very similar).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like Safari doesn't follow the standards for the a tag. I believe [this previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46690722/download-attribute-not-working-in-safari/47998606#47998606) identifies the root cause. From the comments in the linked answer:

> Note that specifying a target attribute in Safari seems to override the download attribute (this does not seem to be the case in Chrome, Firefox or Opera).

Try removing `'_blank'` in your code above and then testing it. It should work!

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how you would open it in a new tab with that change.

Comment: It worked doing everything that they do in your post. Basically, remove the safari check and everything, and create a link that opens (not downloads) the pdf. Thank you!