# Safari download csv file is not working properly, windows.open(url,_blank)

Tags: javascript, safari

In Safari browser, when try to download file with windwo.open() or just creating a link (a tag) then click on it doesn't download to file rather than open file in new tab.

1.

```
window.open(url, '\_blank')
```

2

````
let a = document.createElement("a");
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.style = "display: none";
a.href = \<your_url\>;
a.download = \<your_fileName\>;
a.click();
document.body.removeChild(a);```

3. setTimeout

Expected should be like chrome open new tab and download it
````

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54479139/6133426)? You would have to change the suggested `'data:application/octet-stream;base64,' ...` with something like `'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8, ...` .